# Jquery validate not working properly; show error message on entering the value as well

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have written the code below but even if I enter the fields it shows the error message, also how can I stop the button click if there is another method assigned if it shows error messages.

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/snip.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/action.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('#reg_form').validate({
        rules:{
                FirstName:{
                required:true
                },
                Email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
                ConfirmEmail:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true,
                    equalTo:"#Email"
                },
                code:{
                    number:true
                },
                Mobile:{
                    number:true
                }
        },
        messages:{
                FirstName:{
                    required:"Please enter your First Name"
                },
                Email:{
                    required:"Please provide an Email address",
                },
                ConfirmEmail:{
                    required:"Please provide an Email address",
                    equalTo:"Please provide same Email address"
                }

        }

    });


$('button').on('click',function(){  
    if($('#reg_form').valid()==true)
            $(this).stop();             
});
</script>
```

Here is the [link](http://blues7.esy.es/Salve_project/register.html) to the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `$('#reg_form').validate()({...});`. I.e. you're calling `validate()` with no options and expecting it to return a function, which you're then immediately calling, passing-in options.

You just have a typo; you need to remove the `()` after `validate` so that your options are passed into the `validate` function.